# Generate & transform algorithms doesn't work in c++

Tags: c++, stl

Firstly, i used std::generate to initialize  with an element that have the
value equal with the index:

```
void Gen(std::vector<int> v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        v[i] = i;

}

std::generate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), Gen);
    print(arr);
```

and is not working the bind function .

Also i tried using std::transform to create a new array with the square of the initial range

```
std::vector<int> arr1 = { 4, 6, 3, 8, 1 };
    std::vector<int> newVec1;

std::transform(arr1.begin(), arr1.end(), std::back_inserter(newVec1), [](int i) {return i * i; });
    print(arr1);
```

And this prins the same array

Comment: What is `arr`? Have you read the [documentation for `std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate)? Why do you pass a vector to `Gen`? Why do you pass it by value?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate

Comment: arr is a vector and i read the documentation.

Comment: @loveProgram Doesn't seem so: _...The signature of the function should be equivalent to the following: `Ret fun();`..._ The signature of your `Gen` is completely different.

Answer (score 1):

For your first one, I'd probably advise using `std::iota`, which is defined specifically for cases like yours.

```
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

The second problem seems to be that you're printing out `arr1` (your input) instead of `newVec1` (the result).

Answer (score 0):

That's.... not how generate works. I'm confused how that's even compiling:

```
 clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../include/c++/7.5.0/algorithm:62:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../include/c++/7.5.0/bits/stl_algo.h:4438:19: error: 
      too few arguments to function call, expected 1, have
      0
        *__first = __gen();
                   ~~~~~ ^
main.cpp:19:8: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization
      'std::generate<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *,
      std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, void
      (*)(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)>'
      requested here
  std::generate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), Gen);
       ^
1 error generated.
```

Your generator function (or functor) needs to take no arguments. Here's a mechanism to do what you're suggesting:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Generator {
  int counter = 0;
  int operator()() {
    return counter++;
  }
};

void print(const std::vector<int> &v) {
  for (int elem : v)
    std::cout << elem << " ";
  std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> arr{0,0,0,0};
  std::generate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), Generator());
  print(arr);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
0 1 2 3
```

Comment: 1) `std::vector arr{0,0,0,0};` does not compile. You likely meant something as `std::vector<int> arr(4);` 2) Pass a vector to `print` by const reference.

Comment: @DanielLangr It's an initializer list. it compiles fine. https://repl.it/repls/BetterOutrageousAbility

Comment: I was referring to the missing template argument. But you are right that it compiles, just since C++17. I should have pointed this out; it does not compile with C++11/14.

Comment: @DanielLangr: Whoops. I didn't know that compiles and I didn't realize I missed that. Interesting. (I thought it was the initializer list. It makes sense that it compiles... but weird.)

Comment: I believe it compiles in C++17 due to template argument deduction for class templates. See, e.g., [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction); at the bottom, there is an example with vectors.